# Req.user is undefined and passport.deserializeUser is never been called in express app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-oauth, passport.js

i checked every similar question but no response is useful in my particular case.

i have a simple todo app that i want to use **passport.js** in it.

i have:

- **Express app** (PORT 3001)  and **Reactjs** (PORT 3000) running separately
- **Typescript**
- **express-session**
- **passport-google-oauth20**

when i log in using google strategy everything works fine, the user is created in the Db (if he is not already ) and the redirect to the home is working too.
for the upcoming requests when i try to log **req.user** it prints out undefined

### Passport setup

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(
 new GoogleAuth.Strategy(
{
  clientID:"HIDDEN",
  clientSecret: "HIDDEN",
  callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
},
async (
  accessToken: string,
  refreshToken: string,
  profile: GoogleAuth.Profile,
  done: GoogleAuth.VerifyCallback
) => {
  let user = await getGoogleUser(profile.id);

  if (user) done(null, user);
  else {
    const userObj: any = {
      google: {
        id: profile.id,
        name: profile.displayName,
        email: profile._json.email,
      },
    };

    const newUser = await createGoogleUser(userObj);
    if (newUser) done(null, newUser);
    else done(new Error("error in google auth"));
  }
}));
```

### Auth routes

```
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] }));

router.get("/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000",
  })
);
```

### serialize and deserialize user

```
passport.serializeUser((user: any, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id: string, done) => {
  const user = await getUser(id);
  console.log("deserializeUser");
  done(null, user);
});
```

### Session configuration

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "testasdasdcode",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 },
  })
);
```

### How i am handling the login button in the frontend

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:3001/auth/google";
```

(i know it is very bad practice , but it is for testing for now)

when i log req.user in one of my todo controllers, it shows undefined , also when i try to log anything inside the **deserializeUser** function , nothing shows up.

where the problem could be please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researches,
I found out that i need to supply **withCredentials: true** to any further requests to supply the cookies with the request.

ex :

```
const res = await axios.get(`/auth/getUser`, { withCredentials: true });
```

and in the backend in the cors config object add

```
credentials: true,
```